# Rubyonrails cloud9 to bitbucket to heroku update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bitbucket, cloud9-ide

How do I edit my web page using cloud9 bitbucket after it is launched on heroku?
I have already saved changes on cloud9 and posted a git commit and am in bitbucket.

Do i create a new repository? or how to add to the existing one?

Could someone explain each step?

Comment: If your source code is in bitbucket, you probably used `git` commands to get it there.  Can you post what you did and then let us know your specific question or point out what is not working for you?

Comment: Do i create a new repository? or how to add to the existing one???

Comment: See my answer below.  You should not create a new repository.  The point of `git` is to track all of the changes/versions of your code base within a single repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a `bitbucket` repository set up and reflecting your production code, you should generally be doing the following:

```
git checkout -b new-feature # create repository branch `new-feature` to do more work
... make a bunch of changes and test them ...
git add -A                # add all of your changed files
git commit -am "Meaningful comment"   # comment which goes with your commit describing what you did
git checkout master       # get back to master
git merge new-feature     # ... and merge your changes into it
git push                  # push all of your changes to bitbucket
git push heroku           # deploy to production with Heroku
```

Hopefully, many of these commands are familiar already... otherwise, take a look at the docs to make sure you understand first.

Hope this helps.